# Как сделать UPDATE данных через подготовленые выражения PDO?

Tags: pdo, update

И так, есть код:

```
function msg_read($data) {
    global $pdo;
    $from = $_GET['messages'];
    $to = user_get_id($_COOKIE['user_key']);

    $stmt = $pdo -> prepare('UPDATE messages SET msg_status=read WHERE msg_from_user=? AND msg_to_user=? AND msg_status=new');
    $stmt -> execute($from, $to);
}
```

И ошибка:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute() expects at most 1 parameter, 2 given
>   in /storage/sdcard0/www/shop/functions_message.php on line 133

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: тут прям для вас - http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: Непомогло. Это только усугубило ситуацию

Comment: $stmt -> execute([$from, $to]);

или если у Вас старая версия PHP

$stmt -> execute(array($from, $to));

Comment: Непомогло:Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'read WHERE msg_from_user='2' AND msg_to_user='1' AND msg_status=new' at line 1' in

Comment: как вы видите, подстановка произошла. проблема в самом запросе. для начала напишите так `msg_status="read"` и соответственно `msg_status="new"`

Comment: Аригато годзаимас 

Comment: Доитасимаситэ .